# How to make a web page accessed by manager only. JSP/JSTL

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, jstl

Users are in a mySQL database.

```
Customer (
customer_number INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
surname VARCHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY(customer_number)

CREATE TABLE Manager (
manager_number INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(manager_number)
INSERT INTO Manager VALUES(100, "Jones", "", "Adam", MD5("Adam"), "Erehwon website" );
```

So users are determined by their customer/manager numbers. So if logged in as 1001 that will be a Customer and 100 will be a manager.

So far I have something that checks if a user is logged in so they can view page.

Code:

```
    <%
if (session.getAttribute( "username" ) == null) { %>
<a href="loginpage.jsp">Please Login to buy this item.</a>
<%} else { %>
```

So if the user is not logged in, it will not show the rest of the contents of the page. Only " Please Login to buy this item"

Now I want something like this but for Manager only. So I devised:

```
<%
if (session.getAttribute( "username" ) == ("100")) { %>
<a href="loginpage.jsp">Please Login to buy this item.</a>
<%} else { %>
```

100 being the manager number but it still does not block standard customers from viewing the page.

Comment: Can anyone do this problem???

Answer (score 0):

I think your if condition never returns true. Your session attribute seems that it's storing username. Even if it's your manager number. You should check that like this:

```
session.getAttribute( "username" ) == 100)
```